# Excel Pivot table - get maximum for a period of 24 hours

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excel with:

Days of the week and **24 hours** for each day.

Each hour I get some points.

I would like to calcute the maximum of cumulate points I can get within 24 hours.

[TEST.XLSX]

2 Columns:

```
    Monday  Points
    0   34
    1   32
    2   4
    3   54
    4   12
    5   55
    6   4
    7   4
    8   555
    9   787
    10  8
    11  76
    12  78
    13  8
    14  656
    15  7
    16  4
    17  45
    18  54
    19  543
    20  56
    21  65
    22  4
    23  3
    Tuesday 
    0   56
    1   7
    2   333
    3   9
    4   876
    5   3333
    6   3333
    7   76
    8   3333
    9   465
    10  7
    11  6
    12  5
    13  6
    14  7
    15  6
    16  7
    17  65
    18  555555555
    19  6
    20  5
    21  4
    22  6
    23  6
    Wednesday   
    0   6
    1   7
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please try and describe more of the issue here without a need to download a file. Use pictures, sample data etc.

Comment: Column Two contains "Points earned in an hour" but what does Column One contain?  Sometimes the day, sometimes the hour within the day.  Someone will probably chime in with a formula that gets you what you want with the data set up like this, but I would advise you to change the structure of your data instead, so you can use the built in power of pivot tables.  Maybe _Column 1 = Hour, Column 2 (new) = Day, Column 3 = points earned._  Then you can build a pivot table with _"Day"_ in the rows, sum of _"Points"_ as Values, and throw a little _"max()"_ function on the resulting values column.

Comment: Original Poster - do you want the maximum total for ANY 24 hour period, or the maximum for a day?  In your sample data , the biggest 24 hour period is Hr 19 on Monday - Hr 18 on Tuesday, but Tuesday is the biggest day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use real date time values in your hours column. Delete the rows with the day text. Instead, use a formula that increments from a starting date/time. For example: cell A2 contains the date and midnight time for Nov 17. Cell A3 and copied down contains the formula

=A2+TIME(1,0,0)

which increments by one hour.

Now you con build a pivot table. Group by the date/time value by day and hour. Show the subtotal for the day and set its value field settings to Max.

[image]